# Wordpress better related posts

Tags: wordpress

There are quite some articles describing how to create a related posts utility. This is what I have right now:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post__not_in' => array($current_post_id),
    'posts_per_page'=> 3,
    'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
));
```

The problem with this approach is that posts that have multiple tags in common aren't ranked higher than posts that only have one tag in common. Does anyone know how I can solve this, preferably within the query class?

Thank you

Comment: Note, `caller_get_posts` has been depreciated since version 3.0 (*IIRC*). Turn debug on and you will see the bug in your code. You should be using `ignore_sticky_posts`. You will need to write a complex set of queries and sorting function to achieve what you want

Comment: @PieterGoosen: Thank, must have been an old article.